# Can aircraft fly without wings?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing

Is it possible that a aircraft can fly without having wings? I am wondering if somehow it can fly then will aircraft will be able to maintain the balance.

Comment: highly related: [Can an aircraft fly without wings and stabilizers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54172/3394)

Comment: highly related: [Do airplanes need wings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2883/3394)

Comment: Yes. Soyuz, Shenzhou and Apollo reentry vehicles and all sorts of missiles. And balloons.

Comment: "With enough thrust, anything can fly"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they can, these are called [lifting body aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_body).

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikimedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_body)</sup>

They maintain directional stability using the control surfaces near the tail.

If you like retro documentaries, [here's one on YouTube about lifting bodies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ez2clDxiDv8) done by NASA.

As for aircraft that normally have wings, they can sometimes fly when losing (most) of one of them:

Comment: thank you, very much. @ron-beyer

Comment: Dunno if the F-15 story would qualify on this one as that guy was just very lucky.

Comment: Why not? It wasn't all luck, the F-15 is basically a lifting body at higher speeds, I believe they found that the engine intakes in this case were providing a lot of lift. Either way it's just an example of aircraft flying without both wings.

Answer (score 4):

[Space ship reentry capsule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentry_capsule)

[image]

[Patriot PAC-2 missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Patriot_missile_launch_b.jpg)

[image: Patriot PAC-2 Missile]

[Balloon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balloon)

[image]

[Boeing X-51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_X-51_Waverider), [X-51A](https://storiesbywilliams.com/2013/06/05/eyes-on-the-sky-the-x-51a-goes-hypersonic/) and other [wave riders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waverider)
[image]
[image]